# In Visual Studio, is there a smart way to debug without using temporary variables

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio, you might write code in function using temporary variables like so

```
var fahr = (this.Ce) * 9/5  + 32;
return fahr;
```

or like so

```
return (this.Ce) * 9/5  + 32;
```

I often skip temporary variables, particularly in short functions, however, when debugging, the only way that I know of to evaluate the expression is to do a Ctl-C, Ctl-V into the immediate window. On the other hand, using temporary variables has nice tooling around it.

Is there some way to use VS tooling to easily get the value without using a temporary variable?

Comment: One possible answer is to use Code Rush, which provides a very nice visual debugging experience, however my company went the route of Resharper, so that is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

I always break code down using temporary variables because it's easier to debug, as you pointed out.  If you try to stuff everything into one statement, not only is it harder to debug which part might be failing, but it's also harder to read and figure out what it does when you or someone else is looking at it later.

Visual Studio gives you *some* automatic variables in the "Autos" window, but not all the time, and not for function returns.

Comment: Yeah, the autos window is useful for this. But for some reason it doesn't always work - I was just about to write this answer and did a sample to screenshot. No return value displayed in Autos, no idea why. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the  **(this.Ce) * 9/5  + 32** in the editor, right click and choose Add Watch.